# Highcharts formatNumbers displaying labels and axis incorrectly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm formatting my yAxis values to "millions" (if values are over 1 000 000) and "thousands" (if values are over 1 000). This solution has worked for me:

```
    function formatNumbers(){
    if (this.value >= 1000000 ) return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000000, 0) + "M"
    else if (this.value >= 1000 ) return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000, 0) + "T"
    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,0);
    }
```

I ran into problems, when the data hovers around 100 miljon. One tickmark is displayed two times and the y-scale is thus not linear. JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/avxwkhr8/
The visualisation is displayed below:

[image]

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found such solution that works for me:

```
function formatNumbers(){
                if (this.value <= -1000 && this.value > -1000000 ) return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000, 0) + "K"
                else if (this.value <= -1000000 ) return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000000, 0) + "M"
                return abbrNum(this.value,1); // Need to call the function for each value shown by the chart
            }


function abbrNum(number, decPlaces) {
// 2 decimal places => 100, 3 => 1000, etc
decPlaces = Math.pow(10,decPlaces);

// Enumerate number abbreviations
var abbrev = [ "K", "M", "B", "T" ];

// Go through the array backwards, so we do the largest first
for (var i=abbrev.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

    // Convert array index to "1000", "1000000", etc
    var size = Math.pow(10,(i+1)*3);

    // If the number is bigger or equal do the abbreviation
    if(size <= number) {
         // Here, we multiply by decPlaces, round, and then divide by decPlaces.
         // This gives us nice rounding to a particular decimal place.
         number = Math.round(number*decPlaces/size)/decPlaces;

         // Handle special case where we round up to the next abbreviation
         if((number == 1000) && (i < abbrev.length - 1)) {
             number = 1;
             i++;
         }

         // Add the letter for the abbreviation
         number += abbrev[i];

         // We are done... stop
         break;
    }
}

return number;
```

}